# Should I continue with revisions after two reviewers accepted and one made bullying comments about the research?

Tags: publications, peer-review, interpersonal-issues

I am in the following situation: two reviewers said it was a good investigation and suggested some changes and some new references. But a third reviewer is making bullying comments for the second revision after the other two completely agreed with the publication.

The feeling I get that he is against the publication of the paper and demands almost impossible things. On the first revision, he was very critical about the work, and gave almost three pages of critique that I addressed and answered point by point. After the second revision the other two reviewers were very happy and had no further comments, but this third reviewer wrote another three pages of critique, even revising things he already had made revisions.

I am against a wall after one year of trying to publish the paper, and this new reviewer even makes comments on commas and spaces. Should I continue with the revisions?

Comment: What does the editor say?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/90175/75368

Comment: If someone is careful enough to make comments about spaces and commas, it's worthwhile incorporating these suggestions.

Comment: In what regard is it bullying? Not saying you're wrong, but you haven't described anything that's necessarily bullying in your question. Could you give more detail?

Comment: "Please remember that it is NOT considered the reviewers' task to co-authors your manuscript."   "Again, all co-authors have read and approved this submission, right? If so, the following aspects would seem unclear:" "(this reviewer indeed is astonished, since the (Co-)Authors obviously are not willing to follow the previous recommendations)"

Comment: @Tiago: Some people have a strong personality that can rub you the wrong way. All you can do is ignore comments like the one in the first sentence, and instead address what is brought up (by revisions or rebuttal). It sounds as if you didn't follow this reviewer's suggestions of the prior round, which, if true, is a no-no, and might explain the more personal tone of their 2nd review. Accepting a paper for publication isn't necessarily by majority vote (2 out of 3 like it!). All you can do is to take every feedback seriously.

Comment: That comment referred to a name of company that had Inc. on it and the reviewer said we should remove it

Comment: Funny, I've been through a similar situation on my last paper. Two reviewers found the content publisheable after changes, the third one basically said it wasn't even worth looking.
We authors reviewed and wrote a response for each of the reviewers, treating all as professional as possible.
In the end the editor said the paper is accepted for publication.

By the way, the last reviewer refused to review when the paper returned the second time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should continue. You address your response to the editor, not the reviewer. This is your paper and only your paper, not the reviewers'. Evaluate all the reviewer's comments appropriately. That is, make useful and appropriate changes and reject inappropriate changes with your reasons.

You must assume the editor is serious and sincere and takes both you and the reviewers seriously. The editor might decide to change their view of the need for one or more of the reviewers after you submit your response.

You may explicitly tell the editor that you believe this particular reviewer is hostile to the research. Cite the facts of the two reviews, including that the second review raised entirely new issues and any conflicts between the two reviews as possible evidence. Point out how you decided to make changes based on all the reviews and how they improved the paper.

Reviewers give advice to editors, they don't make publication decisions. The editor can decide that they have had more than enough input from a reviewer and then decide to accept your paper or reject it.

If the editor insists on a third review then two of the reviewers will say they have done what they can or they have had enough, or whatever. If the third one makes more demands and the editor asks you to accede to them, then you decide whether to resubmit to that journal or to withdraw your paper and submit it to another journal.

The editor makes the almost final decision. You make your own final decision. Live with it.

The year everyone has put into the paper already has no bearing on anything. Everyone revision is fresh. Many papers take much more than a year to revise and publish.